# Apache Open NLP training using Max Entropy algorithm with spaces in the key

Tags: java, apache, nlp, opennlp

I am using Apache Open NLP (v- 1.5.3) - Max Entropy algorithm to train the model observing one issue.

I am training a model with below as one of the sample key:values -
"key with space":"value 1","value 2"

```
ObjectStream<DocumentSample> combinedDocumentSampleStream =ObjectStreamUtils.createObjectStream(categoryStreams.toArray(new ObjectStream[0]))
```

When running in debug mode : 
I see that here combinedDocumentSampleStream.streams.category has the correct key i.e.  "key with space" but when I train the model as below and I see the output in DoccatModel  - the outcomeNames are returned with "key" instead of  "key with space".

```
DoccatModel doccatModel = DocumentCategorizerME.train("en", combinedDocumentSampleStream, 0, iterations);
```

Please help me to understand how can I ensure that outcomeNames are returned with actual key i.e. "key with space" instead of just "key"

Comment: OpenNLP 1.5.3 is fairly old. You might want to try the newest version 1.8.4 and see if your problem is still there.

Comment: @jbird : I tried with version 1.8.3(the latest version available in my org repo) and still see  the same issue, wondering if this is an issue with the version or any parameters missing during model training ?

        TrainingParameters trainingParam = new TrainingParameters();         
  trainingParam.put("Iterations",iterations);
  trainingParam.put("Cutoff",0);
  DoccatModel doccatModel = 
  DocumentCategorizerME.train("en",ObjectStreamUtils.concatenateObjectStream(categoryStreams.toArray(new ObjectStream[0]));,trainingParams,new DoccatFactory());

Comment: Hello @Nitin,  Can you rephrase your question.  I don't understand your question.  The OpenNLP data format for the DocumentClassifier line based...  OUTCOME  TOKEN1 TOKEN2 ...  I am not sure what you mean by "key with space".  So a line with dog  bark woof would associate the tokens bark and woof with outcome "dog"  if your line was  dog sound:bark woof  the tokens sound:bark and woof would be associated with dog.

Comment: Hello @HowYaDoing - thanks for responding  <breaking response in two comments due to space constraint>My model structure [I am reading it from DB and NOT from file]:
"welcome"=>"hi","hello","hey"
"goodbye"=>"bye","goodbye","quit"
"key with space"=> "space bar","tab","space"
OUTCOMES:
// this looks OK
OUTCOME:"welcome" 
TOKEN1: "hi"
TOKEN2: "hello"
TOKEN3: "hey"
getting similar outcome for goodbye but have question about below outcome
OUTCOME:"key"
TOKEN1: "space bar"
TOKEN2: "tab"
TOKEN3: "space"

Comment: My training:  
TrainingParameters : Iterations=10000 Cutoff=0
ObjectStream<DocumentSample> docSampleStream = ObjectStreamUtils.concatenateObjectStream(categoryStreams.toArray(new ObjectStream[0]));
NOTE: I see that docSampleStream.streams[6].category => "key with space"
DoccatModel doccatModel = DocumentCategorizerME.train("en", docSampleStream,param,new DoccatFactory());
NOTE: after training the model I see that doccatModel.model->value => "key" and not "key with space"

Comment: My basic question is how can I have a category which has spaces e.g. "key with space" and how can I achieve outcome like below:

OUTCOME:"key with space"
TOKEN1:"space bar"
TOKEN2:"tab"
TOKEN3:"space"

Comment: You mention that "Your model structure ...  welcome=>hi,hello,hey..." OpenNLP has a model structure that is somewhat equivalent to <oversimplified> predictor [outcome1,weight1,outcome2,weight2,...outcomeN,weightN] I am guessing what you mean is that your TRAINING DATA is in a database. At it's lowest level, there is a predicate (read predicator or feature) context so if you have "hi" it probably has a weight (say 1.69) for the outcome "welcome" not no weights for the other outcomes (actually no weight means a weight of 0, this doesnt translate to 0 probablity in the outcome because exp(0)=1

Comment: Anyway, the predictor and all the outcomes are strings, so you there is technically no reason you cant have a space.  The only problem is that all tokenizers used by OpenNLP will split the text your are testing with into the two words and you will never see the token "space bar" just "space" and "bar"  What people usually do is use the bigramFeatureGenerator to make bigrams I think it would be [space,bar].  Another option is to preprocess the text to get make words like space+bar or space-bar.

Comment: This was helpful, I am replacing space with a + and removing when I get it back from model as outcome.